"That right there is why…”

With Duke down by four points in the final seconds of the game, it tried a long on-bounds heave, but to no avail, and the Demon Deacons won a thrilling win, and fans at Lawrence Joel Veterans Memorial Coliseum were so excited that they stormed onto the court.
But as they rushed to the floor, Filipowski appeared to get run into and started limping, and teammates and coaches rushed to help him get off the floor.
The ESPN cameras also caught Filipowski getting helped down the tunnel and into the locker room.
“That should not happen. That right there is why court-storming should not happen,” ESPN analyst Chris Spatola said as the game ended.

Source: https://www.foxsports.com.au/basketball/it-was-personal-intentional-college-stars-fury-after-being-injured-by-rival-fans-in-court-storm/news-story/b0168c9a9610ef0b1abd22055c168517

What does "that" refer to?
What is the grammatical construction of "that right there is why"?


In This right here is X, This right now is X, That right there is X, right is effectively just an optional intensifier before the adverbial term here, now, there (which is itself just an optional intensifying adverb anyway).

That is the demonstrative pronoun referring to the incident involving the player who was injured when fans stormed the court, and right there could be understood as an appositive construction, referring again to the incident via a sort of locative pointer; it adds emphasis, and yields the practical meaning that the incident is a quintessential example of why court-storming should be forbidden.

That (the incident), right there (that very one), is why ....

Let's say a child is playing with matches and burns his finger.  A parent, looking down at the finger, might say:

That, right there, is why you shouldn't play with matches.

P.S. In support of taking "right there" as apposition: the parent looking down at the child's burnt finger could say

Right there is why you shouldn't play with matches.


Also worth noting that right is optional: ‘That there is why…’ is also fine. If there is a noun after this/that, I’d say leaving out right is actually more common: ‘This incident here is why…’ and ‘This incident right here is why…’ are both possible, but the latter seems much less frequent to me than the former.

@JanusBahsJacquet right is an emphatic intensifier in this construction and it can be left out, as you say, but with loss of meaning, as it is what is expressing the "quintessential example" in "That, right there, is why..."  Note that "that there"  is a feature of rural US Southern dialects: *What's that thing, pa? -- Son, that there is a potbelly stove.
